# Python: using select with socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm newbie in Python.
I wrote a socket server. It can read and send json-data. But I need to do it with **select** to extend it.

But I have no idea how to do it. I can't understand examples from the Internet - they have input(), sys.stdin and so on (for what??)

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8888,))
server_socket.listen(5)


while True:
    client, address = server_socket.accept()
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print('received:', data.decode('utf-8'))

    sending_data = bytes(generate_json(), 'utf-8')
    print(sending_data)
    client.send(sending_data)

client.close()
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: You should really consider using the [asyncio module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). [Here's a decent tutorial](http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/the-new-asyncio-in-python-34-servers-pro/240168408) on the subject. It handles all the select stuff for you and gives you a better, event driven, solution to this kind of problem.